# React Focus on dynamically added input

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing code to add input field dynamically when user click on button, then focus on that new added input. Here is my code

```
import {useState, useRef} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(['']);

  const divRef = useRef(null);

  const addInput = () => {
    setValues([...values, ''])
    const lastInput = divRef.current.querySelector('.child:last-child input');
    if(lastInput)
      lastInput.focus()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={divRef}>
       {values.map((v, id) => {
         return (
            <div className="child" key={id}>
              <input onChange={() => {}} value={v}/>
            </div>
         );
       })}              
      </div>
      <button onClick={addInput}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

The problem is rather than focus the last input, it focuses the one before the last input.
[Demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-feather-915cy4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
import {useState, useRef} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(['']);
  const lastInputRef = useRef(null);
  const newInputAdded = useRef(false);

  const addInput = () => {
    setValues([...values, ''])
    newInputAdded.current = true;
  }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (newInputAdded.current === true) {
            lastInputRef.current && lastInputRef.current.focus();
            newInputAdded.current = false;
        }
    }, [values])

  return (
    <>
       {values.map((v, id) => {
         return (
            <div className="child" key={id}>
              <input value={v} ref={r => {lastInputRef.current = r}}/>
            </div>
         );
       })}              
      <button onClick={addInput}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to blur the one before the last input then focus the last input.

Try something like this:

```
 const addInput = () => {
    setValues([...values, ''])
    //blur the one before the last input 
      const beforeLastInput = divRef.current.querySelector('.child:nth-last-child(2) input');
    if(beforeLastInput ){
      beforeLastInput.blur()
    }
    const lastInput = divRef.current.querySelector('.child:last-child input');
    if(lastInput)
      lastInput.focus()
  }
```

Comment: Thank for answering but it does not work